# No such file or directory with hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When I do

```
$ ls
```

I find a file with a name: file_name.csv

However, when I try to do

```
$ hdfs dfs -put /home/user_name/file_name.csv tempfolder
```

(/home/user_name/ is where file_name.csv is located while tempfolder is a tempfolder I created in hdfs). It says

"`/home/user_name/file_name.csv': No such file or directory"

even though it is there. Is there a reason behind this or does anyone know how to fix it?

**Note:** If this is relevant, when I call **hdfs dfs...**, it is with a sudo. So

```
sudoing "hdfs dfs -put /home/user_name/file_name.csv tempfolder"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be running into a shell expansion.  Try a full path to the destination:

```
hdfs dfs -put /home/user_name/file_name.csv /tempfolder
```

Comment: and what if you `hdfs dfs -put file_name.csv /tempfolder`?

Comment: it has to be absolute path because I'm using sudo

Comment: Ah, maybe now we are getting somewhere.  sudo probably can't get at that file because it's in the user dir.  For example, if you `sudo ls /home/user_name` you get the same error?  Can you change the access rights or place the file elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

First, `'/home/user_name/file_name.csv': No such file or directory"` is an error from your local machine. If you see the file with `ls`, then do `$PWD/file_name.csv`

Sudo has very little to do with the problem.

There is a difference between

```
 hdfs:///tempfolder
 hdfs:///user/username/tempfolder
```

And if you `sudo`, you're running the commands as a different user account, not yourself.

The error should be the same for

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/username/tempfolder
```

You **need** a user directory if you don't give an absolute path. In other words, hdfs commands always assume you're writing to your HDFS user folder by default.

> while tempfolder is a tempfolder I created in hdfs

Created how?

Using sudo? Because then the directory won't exist for your user account in HDFS.

Did you create `/tempfolder`? That leading slash is very important and needs to be maintained in your put command

If that HDFS folder didn't already exist, a trailing slash is also important - otherwise, you're copying your CSV to a file without extension named `tempfolder`

Answer (score 0):

The case may arise if the file path is long which was in my case .
For eg.

```
hdfs dfs -put /home/user/folder1/folder2/folder3/demo.csv /usr/input
```

Instead Navigate to the nearest directory then,

```
hdfs dfs -put /folder3/demo.csv /usr/input
```